# Problema al invocar servicio web java. el serializador/deserializador para el parametro es ambiguo porque no se pudo determinar su clase

Tags: java

Estoy intentando invocar un servicio web a través de java, pero cuando ejecuto el código me sale un error que dice :

> el serializador/deserializador para el número de parámetro: 0, nombre:
>   "{http://servicios/}consultarLibrosResponse", tipo:
>   "{http://servicios/}consultarLibrosResponse", es ambiguo porque no se
>   pudo determinar su clase

Por lo que leo es un problema de serialización pero no se como resolverlo debido a que no tengo acceso el código del web service, sino solo deseo implementar un cliente para el mismo.

El código que estoy implementando es:

```
ServiceFactory sf = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
Service serv = sf.createService(
new URL("http://localhost:8080/WSLibreria/libreria?WSDL"),
new QName("http://servicios/", "libreria"));
Call call = serv.createCall(
    new QName("http://servicios/", "libreriaPort"),
    new QName("http://servicios/", "consultarLibros")
);
String result = (String) call.invoke(
    new Object[]{ "novela" }
);
```

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar a resolver esto.

Comment: crea un cliente de web service en netbeans, y se creara una carpeta con los metodos y objetos disponibles del web service, entonces puedes indagar en ep codigo, para ver que parametros reciben los metodosy como tendrias q enviar lis objetos

Comment: ¿Lo solucionaste? Ese tipo de error sucede por lo general cuando se inyecta una dependencia de una interface `X`, pero esa interface la implementan las clases `A`, `B` y `C`, por lo que el contenedor **no sabe** cuál dependencia inyectar. Si colocas parte de tu web service quizás se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

He resuelto mi problema haciendo uso de la utilidad que ofrece java wsimport y un poco de reflection.

La utilidad wsimport lo que hace es crear un paquete con todas las clases necesarias para poder consumir un servicio web, esto lo hace simplemente con ayuda del archivo WSDL del servicio web que se va a consumir.

Luego de crear estos archivos usé las capacidades de reflexión en java para poder ejecutar el servicio. Dado que lo que deseo es crear un cliente para cualquier tipo de servicio y poder ejecutarlo.

A continuación un pequeño ejemplo de como lo solucioné

creé desde java un llamado a wsimport. donde le entrego la URL del wsdl del servicio web y la opción -keep me permite conservar los archivos .java y .class generados

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wsimport -keep http://localhost:8080/WSLibreria/libreria?WSDL");

El wsimport crea un paquete llamado servicios con todos los archivos .java y .class

Luego de eso use reflexión para poder ejecutar el servicio.

```
    Class clase=Class.forName("servicios.Libreria_Service");
    Object service=(Object)clase.newInstance();
    Class clase2=Class.forName("servicios.Libreria");        
    Method metodoGetPort=clase.getMethod("getLibreriaPort");      
    Object obj2=metodoGetPort.invoke(service,null);                 
    Method[] metodosClase2=clase2.getMethods();
    for(Method metodo : metodosClase2){
        if(metodo.getName().equals("consultarLibros")){
            out.print("Encontró el metodo<br>");        
            String resultado=(String) metodo.invoke(obj2,"novela");                
            out.print("rsultado  :"+resultado);
        }
    }
```